# laravel FatalErrorException in the blade template

Tags: php, laravel

I send a variable `response` from my controller to my view.

so in my view if i do this:

```
{{response}}
```

i can see the response, so it is there.

however that `response` is a json format string, so i need to parse it,

i want to do this in the blade.

i tried this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Master Response</title>
</head>
<body>
{{
        $json_a = json_decode($response, true);
        $hits = $json_a['hits']['hits'];
}}
</body>
</html>
```

but i got this error

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
FatalErrorException in 95df32e49f76c09bb366fa2eba52e460d30085dd.php line 7:
parse error
in 95df32e49f76c09bb366fa2eba52e460d30085dd.php line 7
```

Answer (score 0):

The blade system uses `{{ $var }}` to echo data. If you want to do things in PHP in the blade you need to use PHP tags, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Master Response</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
        $json_a = json_decode($response, true);
        $hits = $json_a['hits']['hits'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```